# RStudioでCSVデータの文字を右から2桁で区切りたい場合のスクリプトを知りたい

Tags: r, rstudio

RStudioでCSVデータの文字を右から2桁で区切りたい場合のスクリプトを知りたいです。

Answer (score 1):

tidyverse の stringrを使います。

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, stringr)

> str_sub("string12345", end = -3)
[1] "string123"
```

csvの読み込みでtibble(データフレーム)になった状態なら、
このようにパイプに流します：

```
pacman::p_load(tidyverse, stringr)

tibble <- read_csv("file.csv")

tibble %>%
  mutate(kugiri_kekka <- str_sub(kuguritai, end = -3))
```